# How to access the image files in jhipster app

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, webpack, jhipster

JHipster i using the webpack to serve static files to users, but in my app i want images to load asynchronicly without webpack.
If i understand webpack correctly it is including all files that match the regexp and bundles them.
And any image file that lies in webapp folder will be included
This is the standart image-loader conf for jhipster app.

```
{
                    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/i,
                    loaders: [
                        'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]', {
                            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                            query: {
                                gifsicle: {
                                    interlaced: false
                                },
                                optipng: {
                                    optimizationLevel: 7
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

I store the images url in database and wanted to use the spring resource handler to get the images.

Can anyone please tell me what is the correct way of writing the static resource path for jhipster defoult configuration.

I tryed to use /content/webapp/images/  ...
But it does not seem to work which is strange considered that all static files are located there.